# Expectation of $\ln( 1+bX)$, if $X$ is $\Gamma(\alpha,1)$ distributed

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, special-functions

Assuming I have a Gamma distributed random variable $X\sim\Gamma(\alpha,1)$, $\alpha>1$. $E(X)=\alpha$.

$Y=\ln(1+bX)$, $b$ is a constant.

I like to have a closed form expression of the following expectation value (integrals):
\begin{eqnarray*}
E(Y)=E(\ln(1+bX)) &=& \int_0 ^\infty \ln(1+bx)f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\&=& \int_0 ^\infty \ln(1+bx）\frac{x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{eqnarray*}
I don't know how to get the closed and simplest form of this value $E(Y)$.

Could any expert help me? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: $E(Y)$ is related to $\frac{d}{ds}\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1+bx)^s x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\,dx $ where $\int_{0}^{+\infty}(1+bx)^s x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\,dx $ is a hypergeometric ${}_2 F_1$ function. $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\log(x) x^{\alpha-1}e^{-x}\,dx $ can be evaluated in terms of $\Gamma$ and $\psi$ but the simplest form of $E(Y)$ is not simple at all. On the other hand, numerical approximations are pretty simple to derive.

Comment: Thank you, Jack. Numerical approximation is acceptable. Can you help to derive it?

Comment: For positive and not too large values of $b$ you can get a not so bad approximation by replacing $\log(1+bx)$ with $\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{bx}$ and evaluating the resulting integral through the $\Gamma$ function. This approximation can be refined through different techniques.